# Limit of function as $x \to\infty $ when $f'(x)$ is given

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $f:[1,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R $ is a differentiable function which satisfies $$f'(x)=\frac {1}{x^2+(f (x))^2}  \text{ and } f(1)=1$$ then find the limit of $f $ as $x \to\infty $

**My attempt**: So I first thought of making a differential equation and then calculate the limit. But the differential equation formed $y'(y^2+x^2)=1$ is a non standard equation and it cannot be solved. Even calculators on the internet show that "no solution found". However, Wolfram Alpha does provide a graph but not the solution.

Also $f^{\prime\prime}(x)<0$. Can this fact be used in some way?

Next I thought of using Rolle's theorem but I am unable to figure out some way to use it.

Can anyone provide me some idea on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inverse function satisfies $$x'(f)=x(f)^2+f^2$$ which is a classical Riccati equation. The pole of its solution will be the limit that you are looking for.

You can find a solution in terms of Bessel functions:

- [Riccati differential equation $y'=x^2+y^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446926/riccati-differential-equation-y-x2y2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You can try various estimates with methods like in

- [Riccati D.E., vertical asymptotes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348022/riccati-d-e-vertical-asymptotes)
- [$ y' = x^2 + y^2 $ asymptote](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353727/y-x2-y2-asymptote?noredirect=1&lq=1)

or you can compute a numerical solution.

Comment: Thank you. I got it!

Answer (score 3):

As $f'\left(x\right) >0, f\left(x\right)$ is an increasing function, so we have, for $t>1,f\left(x\right)>f\left(1\right)=1$, Therefore, for $ t>1$,
\begin{align}
f\left(x\right)&=1+\int_{1}^xf'\left(t\right) dt
\\
&<1+\int_{1}^x\frac{1}{t^2+1} dt 
\\
&<1+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2+1} dt
\\
&=1+\frac{\pi}{4}
;
\end{align}
hence, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f\left(x\right)$ exists and is, at most, $$1+\frac{\pi}{4}$$