# Solving a differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please give some hints to solve the differential equation  $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ with f(1)=1 in closed form.

Not coming under the usual non homogeneous form or linear form.

Comment: I don't think that this has a closed form solution.

Comment: The commnd of Maple `dsolve({diff(y(x), x) = 1/(x^2 + y(x)^2), y(1) = 1}, y(x), implicit);` produces $${\frac {-{{ Y}_{-3/4}\left(1/2\right)}-{{ Y}_{1/4}\left(1/2
\right)}}{{{J}_{-3/4}\left(1/2\right)}+{{ J}_{1/4}\left(1/2
\right)}}}-{\frac {-{{ Y}_{-3/4}\left(1/2\, \left( y \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\right)}y \left( x \right) -{{Y}_{1/4}\left(
1/2\, \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}\right)}x}{{{ J}_{-3/4
}\left(1/2\, \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}\right)}y \left( x
 \right) +{{ J}_{1/4}\left(1/2\, \left( y \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{2}\right)}x}}=0
 .$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835521/limit-of-function for a related problem with further links.