# How to determine the Maximal interval of existence for solution of the ODE？

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{align}
    \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}
\end{align}

The reference answer is $(-\infty,\infty)$,or $(-\infty,0)$ or$(0,\infty)$.
I don't know how to deal with the origin.

Comment: Please elaborate your query, its not understandable what are you asking for

Comment: Questions about the same equation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835521/limit-of-function-as-x-to-infty-when-fx-is-given and about the inverse function of the solution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348022/riccati-d-e-vertical-asymptotes