# Prove the solution of differential equation is an odd function and can't be extended on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove that the solution to Cauchy's problem
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> y'=y^2+x^2\\
> y(0)=0
> \end{cases}
> $$
> is an odd function, and that this solution can't be extended on $\mathbb{R}$.

---

I tried to substitute $y(x)$ with $-y(-x)$ and check if cancels out:
$$
\begin{align}
(-y(-x))'=(-y(-x))^2+x^2\\
y'(-x)=y^2(-x)+(-x)^2 && \text{substiute } t=-x\\
y'(t)=y^2(t)+t^2
\end{align}
$$
I think that proves the first part.

---

As for the second part of the question:

let $y$ be a solution to the Cauchy's problem, then:
$$
\begin{align}
y'=y^2+x^2\\
y'\leq y^2\\
\int \frac{dy}{y^2}\leq \int dx\\
\frac{-1}{y}\leq x+c\\
\frac{1}{y}\geq -x+c\\
y\geq \frac{1}{-x+c} \stackrel{x\rightarrow c}{\longrightarrow}\infty
\end{align}
$$

therefore $y$ does not extend on $\mathbb{R}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually the numerical solution gives a result only in $(-2,2)$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348022/riccati-d-e-vertical-asymptote, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353727/y-x2-y2-asymptote, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446926/riccati-differential-equation-y-x2y2 and articles linked from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it correctly:

1. You have only proven that $-y(-x)$ is also a solution. You need to patch this result together with a uniqueness result to achieve that $-y(-x)$ is in fact equal to $y(x)$.
2. You got two mistakes with the inequality signs but they cancel each other out...
   $$
   \begin{align}
   y'=y^2+x^2\\
   y'\color{red}{\geq} y^2\\
   \int \frac{dy}{y^2}\geq \int dx\\
   \frac{-1}{y}\geq x+c\\
   \frac{1}{y}\leq -x+c\\
   y\color{\red}{\geq} \frac{1}{-x+c} \stackrel{x\rightarrow c}{\longrightarrow}\infty
   \end{align}
   $$
   Additionally, to achieve the last line, you should give an explanation why $y>0$, which is straightforward for $x>0, y(0)=0$ and $y'(x)>0$.